# VBA Code to keep non current month data (entire set)

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple set of data i.e., 1 set consists of 3 rows, each set has date column. If any of the set consists of non current month date(out of 3 rows 1 row has non current month in a set), entire set should be retained.

Is this possible to code accordingly? For more reference please see the image how I required the sheet to be generated.

Thanks,

**Image Brief**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. To do it exactly as your request describes, you could use this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
  Dim range_to_check As Range
  Set range_to_check = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E6:E20") '<~ change this to fit your needs

  Dim i As Long
  i = range_to_check.Row + range_to_check.Rows.Count - 1

  Set range_to_check = range_to_check.Cells(1, 1)
  Dim rows_to_delete As Range

  While range_to_check.Row < i
    If Month(Now) = Month(range_to_check.Value) And Month(Now) = Month(range_to_check.Offset(1).Value) And Month(Now) = Month(range_to_check.Offset(2).Value) Then

      If rows_to_delete Is Nothing Then
        Set rows_to_delete = range_to_check.Resize(4).EntireRow
      Else
        Set rows_to_delete = Union(rows_to_delete, range_to_check.Resize(4).EntireRow)
      End If

    End If
    Set range_to_check = range_to_check.Offset(4)
  Wend
  rows_to_delete.Delete

End Sub
```

Still, for this site, you need to show some code. It is to check for errors and stuff like that. Not to get code for free... ;)

Comment: Thank you so much :) :) Sure next time onwards I'll provide the coding too :D. Anyhow Dirk Thank you